# Running SpecFlow tests with different test cases

Tags: selenium, phantomjs, nunit, specflow

NUnit (and the like) has method attributes which allow tests to be run multiple times with different arrange values. Is something similar possible with SpecFlow?

What I am aiming for is a way to run the same scenario tests in a feature file with as many browser drivers as I can, in one test run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use scenario outlines. In example of scenario outline you can mention driver name and you code logic should take action according to driver. Please see more details about scenario ouyline below

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Scenario-outlines

Comment: If the example on that page were modified so that the 'eat' and 'left' column values were placed in their placeholder locations, rather than the Examples table, could the scenario begin with Given I am using <browser> and then have the first Examples column as the names of browser drivers so that each entry can kick off the scenario?

Comment: Yes you can use <browser> in scenario step and in Examples you can provide your different values for <browser>

Answer (score 0):

Examples are one solution, but in your case a little cumbersome, as you have to specify them at every scenario.

In your case, please have a look at the targets feature of the SpecFlow+Runner. With that you can "multiply" your scenarios for different configurations. If you put the web driver that should be used in this configuration, you can test as many webdriver as you want.

Have a look at this example: https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow.Plus.Examples/tree/master/SeleniumWebTest

---

Full Disclosure: I am one of the developers of SpecFlow & SpecFlow+

Answer (score 0):

Use scenario outlines and this tool if you want to use browsers as tags:
https://github.com/unickq/Unickq.SeleniumHelper

[image: https://github.com/unickq/Unickq.SeleniumHelper]